# Getting a relative max for each value in a time series

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table called optiontracking with ConID/TimeLog/Ask/Bid table that looks like the following:

| ConID | TimeLog | Ask | Bid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:18:43 | 0.52 | 0.55 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:20:41 | 0.55 | 0.42 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54 | 0.60 | 0.58 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26 | 0.52 | 0.51 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57 | 0.51 | 0.50 |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 10:25:57 | 0.65 | 0.64 |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 10:26:57 | 0.80 | 0.79 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:18:43 | 1.36 | 1.33 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:20:41 | 1.38 | 1.35 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54 | 1.33 | 1.32 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26 | 1.25 | 1.22 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57 | 1.20 | 1.19 |

What I am trying to get is for each ConID/TimeLog/Ask entry in this table, chronologically next Max(Bid), TimeLog of Max(Bid) while matching the same day and ConID.

I expect to repeat this for Max Ask (but I figure that will need 1 subquery for each group).

So far I have been able to extract the max Bid chronologically after each TimeLog/ask in the dataset using the query below.  I want to be able to pull the corresponding timestamp where the MAX(Bid) was retrieved from, but I am hitting a wall without using a second subquery (which I am trying to avoid due to data size).

Here is the query I am using to get the current max Bid per each Ask Chronologically:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OT.[ConID], OT.[TimeLog], OT.[Ask], MAX(MaxBid.[Bid]) as SellPrice from 
(
SELECT * from algotrading.[optiontracking] WHERE YEAR([TimeLog]) <= 2020 and Month([TimeLog]) <= 6
) as OT

LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT [ConID], [Bid], [TimeLog], CONVERT(date, [TimeLog]) as CombDate from algotrading.[optiontracking] WHERE YEAR([TimeLog]) <= 2020 and Month([TimeLog]) <= 6
) as MaxBid 
on OT.[ConID] = MaxBid.[ConID] and MaxBid.[CombDate] = CONVERT(date, OT.[TimeLog]) and DATEDIFF(second, OT.[TimeLog], MaxBid.[TimeLog]) > 0

GROUP BY OT.[ConID], OT.[TimeLog], OT.[Ask], CONVERT(date, OT.[TimeLog])
```

I know there is a way to get the corresponding [TimeLog] for each Max([Bid]), but I can't quite seem to figure it out.  The Year/Month filtering on each query is because the dataset is too large and I'm trying to do testing first.

Here is what I would expect as an output from the table above (including the TimeLog for each max bid listed as SellPriceTime below):

| ConID | TimeLog | Ask | SellPrice | SellPriceTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:18:43 | 0.52 | 0.58 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:20:41 | 0.55 | 0.58 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54 | 0.60 | 0.51 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26 | 0.52 | 0.50 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57 | 0.51 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 10:25:57 | 0.65 | 0.79 | 2020-06-04 10:26:57 |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 10:26:57 | 0.80 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:18:43 | 1.36 | 1.35 | 2020-06-03 10:20:41 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:20:41 | 1.38 | 1.32 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54 | 1.33 | 1.22 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26 | 1.25 | 1.19 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57 | 1.20 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: SELECT BlaBlaBla ..., MAX(Bid) OVER(PARTITION BY CoID) etcc FROM

Comment: Side note: Are you sure that MAX(bid) is the correct criteria? This assumes that the trader has future knowledge that allows them to ignore earlier lower bids and wait for that later peak. Would a more realistic scenario be that a trade is filled at the first point where the bid matches or exceeds the ask? This also assumes that the ask has not expired, been withdrawn, or been revised. Also, would a trade still occur if the max bid is lower than the ask?

Comment: And why exclude a bid that immediately meets the ask?

Comment: *"due to data size"* if you are concerned about performance avoid using `year(TimeLog)` and `month(TimeLog)` in your where clause. Instead avoid data type conversion completely, just use `where TimeLog < '20200701'` this should maximize the opportunity to use an index on that column.

Comment: @T N I am using this data to train a model in Tensorflow, so I am giving the system many points of data to learn from, then I will let it predict vs. real on my data sets.  Thanks for the question though.

Comment: @Paul Maxwell, thanks for the heads up on that index check, I will change that in the code!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ...)` to select the max bid row for each ask.

An `OUTER APPLY` is like a left join to a subselect, where that subselect can apply `WHERE` conditions, `ORDER BY` and in this case `TOP 1` to get your desired bid. It also allows you to select extract multiple values (`Bid` and `TimeLog` in this case), which is an advantage over a simple `MAX()` function.

I adjusted the "same day" logic to use a condition that checks for TimeLog < start of the next day. The overall date condition in the outer where clause has also been adjusted to be a simple compare. The original logic would have selected the *first 6 months in each year* 2020 and earlier.

For performance, make sure that you have an index on `algotrading.optiontracking(ConID, TimeLog)`.

```
SELECT OT.ConID, OT.TimeLog, OT.Ask, MaxBid.SellPrice, MaxBid.SellPriceTime
FROM algotrading.optiontracking as OT
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 OT2.Bid AS SellPrice, OT2.TimeLog AS SellPriceTime
    FROM algotrading.optiontracking OT2
    WHERE OT2.ConID = OT.ConID
    AND OT2.TimeLog > OT.TimeLog -- Later
    AND OT2.TimeLog < DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(DATE, OT.TimeLog)) -- Before start of next day
    ORDER BY OT2.Bid DESC -- Max Bid
) MaxBid
WHERE OT.TimeLog < '2020-07-01' -- Is this what was intended?
```

Results:

| ConID | TimeLog | Ask | SellPrice | SellPriceTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:18:43.000 | 0.52 | 0.58 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54.000 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:20:41.000 | 0.55 | 0.58 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54.000 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54.000 | 0.60 | 0.51 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26.000 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26.000 | 0.52 | 0.50 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57.000 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57.000 | 0.51 | null | null |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 10:25:57.000 | 0.65 | 0.79 | 2020-06-04 10:26:57.000 |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 10:26:57.000 | 0.80 | null | null |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:18:43.000 | 1.36 | 1.35 | 2020-06-03 10:20:41.000 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:20:41.000 | 1.38 | 1.32 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54.000 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:23:54.000 | 1.33 | 1.22 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26.000 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:26:26.000 | 1.25 | 1.19 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57.000 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 10:28:57.000 | 1.20 | null | null |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rmI3tns4).

Comment: I suggest avoiding year() and month() in the where clause

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Good catch. I tweaked one date compare, but didn't spot the issues with the other one. I have updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @T N Surprisingly, I made a solution for myself that solves this problem (albeit very inelegantly), but it seems to run faster than your query, which I like as a solution a lot more.  Please feel free to chime in as to why you may think my bad solution is faster than yours.

Comment: Without inspecting the query plans, I can only speculate as to why your posted query performs well. Perhaps with sufficient memory, SQL Server is able to load 3 copies of the table and perform hash joins on ConID and the converted date. The query I suggested above requires an efficient OUTER APPLY lookup via an index on algotrading.optiontracking(ConID, TimeLog). Without that index, the join may be executing as a nested table scan, which would likely cause extremely poor performance. (Even a hash join would be limited, because the time condition is a range instead of a date match.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do but this seems like a case for [RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and `PARTITION BY`.

This is not a full answer but with

```
SELECT ConnId, TimeLog, LastPrice, Ask, Bid,
    ,Max(LastPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY ConnId) AS MaxLastPrice  
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ConnId ORDER BY Bid DESC) AS Rank  
from ##Test
```

you'd get:

```
ConnId  TimeLog     LastPrice   Ask     Bid     MaxLastPrice    Rank
1   2020-06-04 10:26:57.0000000     10.48   0.80    0.79    10.48   1
1   2020-06-04 10:25:57.0000000     10.48   0.65    0.64    10.48   2
1   2020-06-03 10:23:54.0000000     10.45   0.60    0.58    10.48   3
1   2020-06-03 10:18:43.0000000     10.40   0.52    0.55    10.48   4
1   2020-06-03 10:26:26.0000000     10.42   0.52    0.51    10.48   5
1   2020-06-03 10:28:57.0000000     10.48   0.51    0.50    10.48   6
1   2020-06-03 10:20:41.0000000     10.30   0.55    0.42    10.48   7
2   2020-06-03 10:20:41.0000000     12.05   1.38    1.35    12.15   1
2   2020-06-03 10:18:43.0000000     12.10   1.36    1.33    12.15   2
2   2020-06-03 10:23:54.0000000     12.03   1.33    1.32    12.15   3
2   2020-06-03 10:26:26.0000000     12.13   1.25    1.22    12.15   4
2   2020-06-03 10:28:57.0000000     12.15   1.20    1.19    12.15   5
```

You can now order by whichever column you wish and pick the records with rank 1, for example.

---

Here's my test data:

```
CREATE TABLE ##test (
    ConnId INT,
    TimeLog DATETIME2,
    LastPrice Numeric(5,2),
  Ask Numeric(5,2),
  Bid Numeric(5,2)
);


Insert into ##test values
(1, '2020-06-03 10:18:43 ', 10.40, 0.52, 0.55),
(1, '2020-06-03 10:20:41 ', 10.30, 0.55, 0.42),
(1, '2020-06-03 10:23:54 ', 10.45, 0.60, 0.58),
(1, '2020-06-03 10:26:26 ', 10.42, 0.52, 0.51),
(1, '2020-06-03 10:28:57 ', 10.48, 0.51, 0.50),
(1, '2020-06-04 10:25:57 ', 10.48, 0.65, 0.64),
(1, '2020-06-04 10:26:57 ', 10.48, 0.80, 0.79),
(2, '2020-06-03 10:18:43 ', 12.10, 1.36, 1.33),
(2, '2020-06-03 10:20:41 ', 12.05, 1.38, 1.35),
(2, '2020-06-03 10:23:54 ', 12.03, 1.33, 1.32),
(2, '2020-06-03 10:26:26 ', 12.13, 1.25, 1.22),
(2, '2020-06-03 10:28:57 ', 12.15, 1.20, 1.19)
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but I think I may have overcomplicated the question by adding in the LastPrice column.  I'm trying to get a Max(Bid), and associated TimeLog next in chronological order for each ConID, TimeLog, Ask.  Essentially the "Ask" is the buy price, and I'm trying to find the top "Bid" or sell price that occurs in time and the exact time the thing sold, each ConID is a different "item" per say.  Hope that explains it better

Comment: My current query finds the next top price for each ask as it goes through the list, but I am struggling to pull in the date associated with the sell price (Max[Bid]).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the way I knew how, and it is faster than the current "better" solution.  I would much rather use @T N's answer which is easier to understand and seems way more flexible, but this is query is considerably faster (3.5 mins vs. 8 mins).

For some extra information:

- There is roughly 8 million records in this table for data from 6/1/2020 to 7/1/2020
- There were no indexes created yet to help with any of these queries.

Any guidance as to why this is a significantly faster query than @T N's answer?

```
SELECT Prof.[ConID], Prof.[PurchaseTime], Prof.[Ask], Prof.[MaxPriceAfterPurchase], Prof.[MaxPriceAfterPurchase]-Prof.[Ask] as MaxProfit, MIN(SellTimeMax.TimeLog) as SellAtMaxTime
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT OT.[ConID], OT.[TimeLog] as [PurchaseTime], OT.[Ask], MAX(MaxBid.[Bid]) as MaxPriceAfterPurchase
  from (
  SELECT * from algotrading.[optiontracking] WHERE TimeLog < '2020-07-01'
  ) OT

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [ConID], [Bid], [TimeLog], CONVERT(date, [TimeLog]) as CombDate from algotrading.[optiontracking] WHERE TimeLog < '2020-07-01'
    ) MaxBid 
    on OT.[ConID] = MaxBid.[ConID] and MaxBid.[CombDate] = CONVERT(date, OT.[TimeLog]) and DATEDIFF(second, OT.[TimeLog], MaxBid.[TimeLog]) > 0

  GROUP BY OT.[ConID], OT.[TimeLog], OT.[Ask]
) Prof
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT [ConID], [Bid], [TimeLog], CONVERT(date, [TimeLog]) as CombDate from algotrading.[optiontracking] WHERE TimeLog < '2020-07-01'
) SellTimeMax
ON SellTimeMax.[ConID] = Prof.ConID and SellTimeMax.CombDate = CONVERT(date, Prof.[PurchaseTime]) and SellTimeMax.[Bid] = Prof.[MaxPriceAfterPurchase] and DATEDIFF(second, Prof.[PurchaseTime], SellTimeMax.[TimeLog]) > 0
GROUP BY Prof.[ConID], Prof.[PurchaseTime], Prof.[Ask], Prof.[MaxPriceAfterPurchase], Prof.[MaxPriceAfterPurchase], Prof.[Ask]
```